# Ошибка при отправке заголовков в php

Tags: php, cookie, http-заголовки

Нужно отправить заголовки после бд, чтобы получилось так

```
include __DIR__ . '/../../database/db.php';

$user = $db->real_escape_string($data['user_id']);
$access_token = $db->query("SELECT `access_token` FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = '$user'")->fetch_column();

if (empty($access_token)) {
  $access_token = md5($data['access_token']);
  $db->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_name`, `access_token`) VALUES ('$user', '$access_token')");
}

setcookie("access_token", $access_token, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30), '/');
header('Location: /');
```

Но проблема в том что когда выполняешь `include` бд то заголовки отправить уже нельзя, как можно решить данную проблему и поможет ли с этим `ob_start(); ob_flush();`

Comment: *"когда выполняешь include бд то заголовки отправить уже нельзя"* --- это неправда. Это означает только одно - в файле с бд уже есть что-то, что отправляет заголовки

Comment: @Алексей Где?  `<?php
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] != 'localhost') {
 $db_user = 'fff';
 $db_password = 'fff';
 $db_db = 'fff';
} else {
 $db_user = 'root';
 $db_password = 'root';
 $db_db = 'topdrop';
}

$db_host = 'localhost';

$db = new mysqli(
 $db_host,
 $db_user,
 $db_password,
 $db_db
);
`

Comment: где угодно. Может до открытия тега php какие-либо лишние символы (файл в кодировки UTF-8 c BOM), а может подключение даёт какой-то warning, который можно увидеть в ответе от сервера. ... как вариант влияет не сам include, а код уже в текущем файле, который работает с БД и тоже "корявый" и выкидывает warnings или notice которые и обламывают всё. ..... так что надо для начала проверить чистый include и header(/) и убедиться, что проблема не  в нём

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Это всё что есть в этом файле, вот ссылка https://dropmefiles.com/fFK5z

Comment: Ещё раз: сделай include банально пустого файла. А в текущем сделай только перенаправление и убедишься что всё работает.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А я скажу так я не удалял ничего в include просто оставил 
`    include __DIR__ . '/../../database/db.php';

    header('Location: /');`
и ошибки не было

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я решил, рассказать как?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в запросе к бд сравните код

```
    include __DIR__ . '/../../database/db.php';

$access_token = $db->query("SELECT `access_token` FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = '$data[user_id]'")->fetch_assoc();

if (empty($access_token)) {
  $access_token = md5($data['access_token']);
  $db->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_name`, `access_token`) VALUES ('$user', '$access_token')");
} else {
  $access_token = $access_token['access_token'];
}

setcookie("access_token", $access_token, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30), '/');
header('Location: /');
```

Comment: что и требовалось доказать.... проблема не в инклуде